# After successfully adding a gradle dependency for a .jar file in mavenLocal(), how do I actually import and use that jar from a java class

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Using mvn install I have a jar file that I can compile with gradle using the dependency:

`compile files('org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-excel/0.5.0-SNAPSHOT/*.jar')`
 and adding the mavenLocal() repository

But I don't know how to actually use this jar in my java code.  Copying the config from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/blob/master/spring-batch-excel/README.md doesn't work.  The link gives the import lines

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.mapping.PassThroughRowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader;
```

But Intellij has a problem finding the .excell directory, which is where the files in the jar add new things to the spring framework, which tells me that it's not looking in the jar I added.  How do I make it do that?

The jar file contains src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/excel/[useful things]

I also generated metadata for intelliJ after maven install with `maven idea:idea` but I don't know where to put the two files it created (.iml and .ipr)

Comment: do you see this dependency in the "external libraries" on the left side of the project in Intellij?

Comment: No i don't.  What can I do about that?  The gradle file compiles successfully, which means that it's finding the file when it looks for it.

Comment: I tried invalidating caches and restarting which was a suggestion I found somewhere, but that didn't work

Comment: I've resolved the errors by adding the jar in the local repository to my external libraries manually.  I'm a little worried about this though.  Eventually this code will be running on a server, and I'm not familiar enough with spring boot to know if dependencies in my local repository will be taken care of without any problems.

Comment: *"The gradle file compiles successfully, which means that it's finding the file when it looks for it."* - This is just plain wrong. Gradle does not care at all if it cannot find a (file) dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up some things:

1. Adding the `mavenLocal()` repository has absolutely no impact on file dependencies (like the one you specified). It allows you to import dependencies you've installed via `mvn install` as external dependencies by specifying their classifier (`<group>:<id>:<version>`), the same way you import dependencies from `mavenCentral()` or `jcenter()`.
2. The [`files(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files-java.lang.Object...-) method does not allow wildcards, so in your example it searches for a file with the exact name `*.jar`. Also, since you provide a relative path, it starts with this relative path from the project directory. You can either pass the correct and exact paths of all required files as consecutive arguments to the `files(...)` method or use a [`fileTree`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#fileTree-java.util.Map-) to specify a base directory and a name with wildcards.